# Booting a Sony Vaio VGN FE31H from USB stick when BIOS has no such option

Tags: boot, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive

I have a laptop [Sony Vaio VGN FE31H](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/vgn-fe31h) which has Windows installed and I wanted to boot a Linux distribution from USB stick. Unfortunately the BIOS has no such option.

I am looking for a suitable boot loader which will give me an option to boot from USB. Is this the right way to go about it? Or do you think its not possible if BIOS does not show an option to boot from USB ?

Comment: Does the laptop use UEFI (the new stuff with Secure Boot and CSM mode), or does it use BIOS (the old stuff)?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a laptop Sony Vaio VGN FE31H which has windows installed and I wanted to boot a linux distribution from USB stick. Unfortunately the BIOS has no such option... I am looking for a suitable boot loader which will give me an option to boot from USB. Is this the right way to go about it?

Convert the USB stick to a bootable ISO DVD. See, for example, the [Burning ISO HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto). [This bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1043274) also provides a script to do some of the ISO conversions for you. If you know scripting, then you can probably do it on your own.

If you can't boot from a DVD either, then fetch a "network install" of your Linux distribution and burn that to CD. It will be small (a couple of hundred of MB) and it will fetch what it needs from the network.